# Unknown column 'readingid' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, sqlyog

```
SELECT
a.objid AS acctid,
a.acctno,
a.name,
a.meterid,
m.serialno,
(
    SELECT
    objid
    FROM
    waterworks_meter_reading r
    WHERE r.meterid = a.meterid
    AND r.month = 6
    AND r.year = 2015
    LIMIT 1
) AS readingid
FROM waterworks_account a
INNER JOIN waterworks_meter m ON a.meterid = m.objid
INNER JOIN waterworks_account_address ad ON a.objid = ad.parentid
WHERE ad.barangayid LIKE '%'
AND readingid IS NULL
```

When I tried to execute the query above it throws an error: **Unknown column 'readingid' in 'where clause'**. Can someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, you cannot reference a column alias defined in a `select` in the `where` clause at the same level (or elsewhere in the `select`).

MySQL has a convenient work-around, in some cases.  You *can* reference it in a `having` clause.  So this should do what you want:

```
WHERE ad.barangayid LIKE '%'
HAVING readingid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the "readingid" isn't really a column name. It exists in the select but that happens after the where clause. I would use a nested query to get the "readingid" so it is available for the where clause.

For example:

```
 SELECT
a.objid AS acctid,
a.acctno,
a.name,
a.meterid,
m.serialno FROM waterworks_account a
INNER JOIN waterworks_meter m ON a.meterid = m.objid
INNER JOIN waterworks_account_address ad ON a.objid = ad.parentid
WHERE ad.barangayid LIKE '%'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT
    objid
    FROM
    waterworks_meter_reading r
    WHERE r.meterid = a.meterid
    AND r.month = 6
    AND r.year = 2015)
```